# changing values in a column of data set using regex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is a subset of a data frame:

```
Index     duration 
1          4  months20mg 1X D
2          1  years10 1X D
3          2  weeks10 mg
4          8  years300 MG 1X D
5          20  days
6          10  months
```

The output should be like this:

```
Index     duration 
1          4  month
2          1  year
3          2  week
4          8  year
5          20  day
6          10  month
```

This is my code:

```
df.dosage_duration.replace(r'year[0-9a-zA-z]*' , 'year', regex=True)
df.dosage_duration.replace(r'day[0-9a-zA-z]*' , 'day', regex=True)
df.dosage_duration.replace(r'month[0-9a-zA-z]*' , 'month', regex=True)
df.dosage_duration.replace(r'week[0-9a-zA-z]*' , 'week', regex=True)
```

But it does not work. Any suggestion ?

Comment: `df.duration.str.replace('((?<=year)|(?<=month)|(?<=week)|(?<=day)).*', '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems.

The first is that your regular expression doesn't match all the parts you want it to match. Look at `months20mg 1X D` - there is a space in the part you want to replace. I think you could probably just use `'year.*'` as your matches.

The second is that you are calling `replace` without storing the results. If you want to do the call the way you have, you should specify `inplace=True`.

You can also use a single call if you use a slightly extended regular expression. We can use `\1` to refer to the first matching group for the regular expression. The groups are indicated by the parentheses:

```
df.dosage_duration.replace(r'(year|month|week|day).*' , r'\1', 
                           regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: thank you. Would you please explain how r'\1' works ?

Comment: Also, if it is guarrented that the day,week,month,week end with an s, I guess, you can simply do this `df.dosage_duration.split('s')[0]`.

Comment: @Mary I've added to my answer.

Comment: @officialaimm, what is the meaning of [0] at the end of your code ?

Comment: Take first(0-indexed) half from the split i.e. the part left to the 's'. split() returns an array `['4 month', '20mg 1X D']`. Now the 0th element of the array is what we are interested in.